# Making dropdown menu in html & css with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html

This is my problem in my `<li class="drop-down"><a href="#"></a></li>` then my position in my page is in bottom then when I click that -> drop-down <- then my page is going on top how can i fix that problem, my navigation bar is fixed position.

Comment: could you please show your code or snapshot

Comment: you need to return false or preventDefault when you click on `#` link, otherwise it will go to top of the page, as id is not defined ..

Comment: Create a jsfiddle and share..

Comment: Why use a link at all, if you're not going to use it as a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
href="#"
```

casuses that issue for you. Try linking it to an actual item in your page. Or what you could do:

```
href="#!"
```

or a third option:

```
href="#" class="stop"
```

with jQuery

```
$('.stop').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is the normal behaviour of any browser, that it will navigate to the top of your page if you click on an anchor that's href ttirbute is a hash "#".
        
If you want to prevent this behaviour, please leve the hash away, or prevent it by using Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following without JavaScript

```
<a href="javascript:;>My link</a>
```

Or

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);">My link</a>
```

Comment: Ty very much Ma'am ^^